# When did Red Hat start shipping PHP 5.3 with 5.x?

Tags: php, rhel5

Okay this is a PSA more than a question because I know the answer: January 13, 2011.

See: https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHEA-2011-0069.html

Colour me surprised though, didn't hear anything about in the blogosphere until I got a Security Errata [notice](http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2011-0196.html) today.

I have been using the REMI repo for this in the past but will switch over to the Red Hat blessed PHP 5.3.

Don't down-vote me bro! I'll select as the best answer the source that broke the news first (other than Red Hat of course). People have wanted this for so long I'm just amazed that it's finally happened!

Comment: Very nice that RedHat has a recent version of PHP, but not really a SF question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since 5.6

http://meetbot.fedoraproject.org/fedora-meeting/2009-09-11/fedora-meeting.2009-09-11-21.00.log.html

> 21:35:27 <derks> I started the IUS project due to the demand that our customers have for the latest and greatest versions of only a small set of packages: PHP/MySQL/python.. etc
>
> 21:37:26 <derks> php52, php53, mysql50, mysql51, python26 (plus a few supporting python26 packages)
>
> 21:37:32 <derks> all following upstream stable

http://meetbot.fedoraproject.org/fedora-meeting-1/2010-02-27/fedora-meeting-1.2010-02-27-17.12.log.html

> 19:35:00 <smooge> no 5.6 will have php53